# Update row value only when all other rows meet the condition

Tags: sql-server

I'm having some issues with this seemingly simple table. I'm trying to change the value of the NEW_LVL column rows to either 1 (if all the TRAINING_LVL rows have the value 1) or 0 (if one of the TRAINING_LVL rows has the value 2), in this case for NEW_NR value 10.

```
USER_NR TRAINING_NR TRAINING_LVL NEW_NR NEW_LVL
49867   8400              2        10      0
49867   8490              1        10      1
49867   8480              1        10      1
```

So far I've been trying to use the CASE method to change it but I can't seem to be able to change it so that it only modifies the NEW_LVL value when all of the rows meet the condition. Instead, it is changing the value for each individual row, if they meet the condition.

```
UPDATE dbo.MTD
    SET NEW_LVL =
    CASE
        WHEN NEW_NR = 10 AND TRAINING_LVL = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
```

What would be a better way to do this? I have tried using the HAVING clause, rather unsuccessfully.

Comment: `mysql <> sql-server` pick one!

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store values calculated from other columns. (Risk of data inconsistency.) Either create a _view_, or have a _computed column_, to be safe.

Comment: @jarlh How do you create a computed column inside a CASE?

Comment: @StefanEsteban you don't. Details of generated columns are stored along the table structure. Please refer to [Specify Computed Columns in a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query -

**This is query will return count > 0 if any of record having TRAINING_LVL !=1 and NEW_NR = 10 If the count is > 0 it means you need to update 0 else 1**

```
declare @count int
 select @count = count(1) from mtd where TRAINING_LVL != 1 and NEW_NR = 10
 print @count
```

**This query will update the value in the table as needed.**

```
update mtd
 set NEW_LVL = (case when @count> 0 then 0 else 1 end)
 where NEW_NR = 10
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE`!

```
UPDATE dbo.MTD
    SET NEW_LVL = 1
    WHERE NEW_NR = 10 AND TRINING_LVL = 1
```

If you use `CASE`, you can have `ELSE NEW_LVL`, but it is better to use `WHERE`.

Comment: Yep I know this works but this sets the value for each individual row. I am trying to only change the NEW_LVL column if all the rows meet the TRAINING_LVL requirement of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Going with the comment from @jarlh, we can try just writing a query which will output things as you want:

```
SELECT
    USER_NR,
    TRAINING_NR,
    TRAINING_LVL,
    NEW_NR,
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MTD
                          WHERE TRAINING_LVL <> 1 AND NEW_NR = 10)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NEW_LVL
FROM dbo.MTD;
```

Note that if you wanted the new level to reflect a particular user only, or some other partition, then we would have to correlate the exists query.  Assuming you wanted to report per user, here is a way to do that:

```
SELECT
    USER_NR,
    TRAINING_NR,
    TRAINING_LVL,
    NEW_NR,
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MTD t2
                          WHERE t2.USER_NR = t1.USER_NR AND t2.TRAINING_LVL <> 1 AND
                                t2.NEW_NR = 10)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NEW_LVL
FROM dbo.MTD t1;
```

Comment: This returns the NEW_LVL values as 0 for all the rows. Maybe I didn't explain it that well in the initial question. So there's these training packages (NEW_NR) that contain several smaller trainings (TRAINING_NR). A user has passed the training if the TRAINING_LVL is 1 and failed if the value is 2. 

In order to qualify for the whole training (NEW_LVL), all of the smaller trainings have to be passed. Thus, for example if the NEW_NR is 10, the NEW_LVL for it can only have the value 1 if all of the previous modules are passed.

Comment: @StefanEsteban `if all the TRAINING_LVL rows have the value 1` ... this certainly sounds to me like a table/partition aggregation.  Maybe I read wrongly, or maybe you did not explain properly.

Comment: I probably didn't explain it properly, sorry :( To simplify, the main problem I'm having is that the query is calculating the result based on each individual row's value (ex if the TRAINING_LVL is 1, then the NEW_LVL also gets the value 1, even though another row has the value 2 for the same NEW_NR).

Comment: I updated my answer again, though I see you have already accepted another answer.

Comment: Thank you man! Sorry if I explained it badly or wasted your time. I selected that answer cause it's the closest thing to what I had in mind. I'm really happy to see that so many ppl jumped to my aid, will definitely be using StackOverflow again. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This;

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE dbo.MTD SET  NEW_LVL = '0' WHERE TRAINING_LVL=2 AND NEW_NR=10; 

UPDATE dbo.MTD SET  NEW_LVL = '1'  WHERE TRAINING_LVL=1 AND NEW_NR=10; 
COMMIT
```